# Observe array and fold it to string

Tags: ios, cocoa, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

I'm new to FRP and MVVM, but so far it is gone well but I have a problem now with observing an array on my model and when it is set fold it to a string.

```
RAC(self, tags) = [[RACObserve(self.deal, tags) sequence] foldLeftWithStart:@"" reduce:^id(NSString *accumulator, NSString *value) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@#%@ ", accumulator, value];
}];
```

The above code just halts the app.

**Update**

So I figured it out, so typical

```
RAC(self, tags) = [RACObserve(self.deal, tags) map:^id(NSArray *tags) {
    return [[tags rac_sequence] foldLeftWithStart:@"" reduce:^id(NSString *accumulator, NSString *value) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@#%@ ", accumulator, value];
    }];
}];
```

But is this the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
RAC(self, tags) = [RACObserve(self.deal, tags) map:^(NSArray *tags) {
    return [@"#" stringByAppendingString:[tags componentsJoinedByString:@"#"]];
}];
```

Comment: Doesn't quite give the desired output, if I would use `componentsJoinedByString:` it would look like `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%@", [tags componentsJoinedByString:@" #"]]`.

So which one is the most reactive...

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I've updated my answer. It's not "reactive", but nor is using sequences, but it is functional.

Comment: Kind of tangentially related, but take a peek here as well: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/890

There's some discussion there about the future of sequences, collections, and signals that you might find interesting.